# ggplot2 and usa <- map_data('state'): Why is this map smooshed and how can it be fixed?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a map of the US States using ggplot2 and `usa <- map_data('state')`.  The following code keeps the aspect ratio fixed, but incorrect (it's too short and wide).  How can this be fixed?

```
ggplot(data = hiv_data, mapping = aes(x= long, y= lat, group = group, fill = delta)) +
  geom_polygon(color="blue") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    limits=range(5,-175),
    low = "blue",
    high = "white"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "", 
    title = "Change in HIV per 100000 from 2008 to 2020"
  ) +
  theme( 
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  ) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: What is your hiv_data?

Comment: Does the map look better if you use `coord_sf(default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326))` instead of `coord_equal()`? [Source](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html)